# Routing ports on same IP to different ELBs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm working with a new setup and setting up two services behind ELBs:

- ELB #1 on port 143
- ELB #2 on port 80

I want to have both services available on the same external IP, whether another ELB or an Elastic IP or whatnot.  However, I can't seem to add an ELB to an ELB, so that doesn't seem to be the solution.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Can't you do this with two listeners, one per protocol/port combination and route to different target groups?

Comment: @jarmod, the snag in that (otherwise excellent) plan may be that port 143 is IMAP, but ALB only supports HTTP, not raw TCP.

Comment: I thought the target groups only worked for HTTP; I need IMAP in there too.  Do you have an example?

Comment: Comment collision.  Correct, only Classic ELB can do TCP (non-HTTP).  So the 80 and the 143 services are on different back-end instances from each other?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Correct.  One set is handling the IMAP service, another set is handling the web.

Comment: This is an impossible combination using ELB or ALB without some 3rd party components.  Why not two hostnames?  I'm guessing legacy reasons, but if you can elaborate on why one hostname needs to point to two different clusters for two different services, perhaps there's a useful alternative.  Also, is a single or static external IP address important? If so, you have *two* problems, but that may help nail down a workable option, since ELB/ALB do not use static addresses (they don't change often, but they do change).

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't thinking about IMAP for some reason. I'd prefer to manage example.com and imap.example.com, personally. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

Its Possible if you use **Route53.**

Chose a Route53 routing policy according to your scenario.

Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html

Attach your two Elastic load balancers to Route53.
Now your route53 handles traffic and routes it to the the 2 ELBs.
And then your ELBs recieve traffic and route it to their respective resources.

Hope It Helps.. :)